# How to send Google form applicants to Org Charts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

I need to automate the applicant and position ownership processes:
Forms> Acceptance> Plug them into an Org chart

Let me know if I can provide more use case info. I tried using Apps Script.

Thank you,

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you currently have and what you are trying to accomplish so that we can better understand the question.

Comment: Hey Fernando,
I'm currently working on the minimal reproducible example.
I need this integromat functionality, but I just don't want leaders notified on Slack. Just through email.

https://www.integromat.com/en/integration/6103-create-new-users-in-google-workspace-from-new-google-form-responses-and-notify-all-included-parties-via-email-and-slack

Thank you,

Comment: So if I understand correctly what you need is to create something similar to what they have but with some differences, right?

Comment: That's correct. I think I should be able to use Apps Script, but I'm not seeing very good documentation on this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use Google Apps Script to accomplish this.

First you need to create a Google Form the users will need to fill and get the data of that form in a spreadsheet. Once you have the spreadsheet you can start using Google Apps Script to create the users based on the data from the spreadsheet.

There is a code sample on how to create users in the Admin console using Google Apps Script [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory#add_user). I am assuming you will create your script so that it can add users based on the information introduced in the data from the spreadsheet, so you have the list of methods you can use [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#methods).

You would also need to add a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) to your script so it starts running every time the spreadsheet gets edited, meaning that a user will get automatically created by the script every time someone fills the form and the responses get recorded in the spreadsheet.